# Creating a new spreadsheet using Google Drive's REST API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I am building a chrome-extension and would like to enable users to create a new spreadsheet. Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads). Here is how I am attempting to do it:

```
Sweeper.GSheets.prototype.createSpreadsheet = function(title) {
  var data, headers, callback, delimiter, boundary;
  callback = function(status, responseText){
    console.log(responseText);
  };

  title = title + ' --CD.xls';
  delimiter = '\r\n';
  boundary = '--Sweeper';

  data = boundary + delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' + delimiter + delimiter + '{' + delimiter + '"title"' + ': ' + '"' + title + '"' + delimiter + '}' + delimiter + delimiter + boundary + delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' + delimiter + ' ' + delimiter + boundary + '--';  

  headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="Sweeper"', "Convert": "true" };

  this.makeRequest('post','https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart', callback, data, headers );


};


Sweeper.GSheets.prototype.makeRequest = function(method, url, callback, opt_data, opt_headers) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var data = opt_data || null;
    var headers = opt_headers || {};

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

    // Include common headers (auth and version) and add rest. 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + State.authToken());

    for (var key in headers) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
    }

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      this.lastResponse = e.srcElement;
      callback(e.srcElement.status, e.srcElement.responseText);
    }.bind(this);

    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
      Sweeper.log(this, this.status, this.response,
          this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    };
    xhr.send(data);
  }.bind(this), 500);
};
```

This actually creates a document that Google Drive recognizes as a spreadsheet, however, I cannot view the sheet. When I click on it, I receive a generic error.

Does anyone know how to make this request so that it creates an empty spreadsheet?

Comment: No offense, but did you even read the documentation? It clearly states to use the Google Drive API.

Comment: that's what i linked to, but the page used to include an example and is no longer there.

Comment: ive updated my answer

Comment: too bad after updating my answer and providing working code someone still downvoted so Ive deleted my answer.

Comment: I just got to this today. Oh well, but regarding what you mentioned about the example no longer being there, I will ping Google and see if they can direct me.

Comment: ok  un-deleted. someone seems to be serially downvoting my answers oh well hope he feels better :)